# Email with Google Script Editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, macro-recorder

I know there are two separate email functions in the code but the one I am trying to get to work is the `sendsheettopdfwithA2mailaddress`.

Every time I try to delete the other one I get an error message so any help with deleting that and everything still work would be greatly appreciated too. The error message is

> Exception: Request failed for docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: `<HTML><HEAD>`

The main issue that I'm having is that I only want to email one sheet which is the main one or 0. When it sends the email it sends 12 different sheets and sheet 0 is very condensed to about a quarter of the sheet.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()          //gets the active spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()  //gets the active sheet
  var cell = ss.getActiveRange()               //gets the active cell
  var cellContent = cell.getValue()            //gets the value of the active cell
  
  if(cellContent === 'BOXCHECKED') {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('B1:H4').activate();
    var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1:H55').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=H5');
    spreadsheet.getRange('H56').activate();
    spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);
    spreadsheet.getRange('\'Quote Sheet\'!A1:H55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
                                                          SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    spreadsheet.getRange('\'Quote Sheet\'!A1:H55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
                                                          SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data Sheets'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('2:35').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 34);
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 34, 
                                        spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Quote Sheet'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('B11').activate();
    currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A12:z44').activate();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data Sheets'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('\'Quote Sheet\'!A12:z44').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
                                                           SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Quote Sheet'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRangeList(['C5:C10', 'H6:H10', 'B12:B44','D12:E44', 'H49:H50','B51:E55']).activate();
    spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('H49'));
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('G53').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('False')
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Quote Sheet')
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function (sh) 
                                                   {
                                                     sh.setName(sh.getRange('a1').getValue())
                                                   })
  } 
};

function renameSheets() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function (sh) {
    sh.setName(sh.getRange('A1').getValue())
  })
};

/* Email Google Spreadsheet as PDF */
function emailGoogleSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  
  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "t.mitchellbivens@gmail.com"; 
  
  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "PDF generated from spreadsheet " + ss.getName(); 
  
  // Email Body can  be HTML too 
  var body = "Install the <a href='http://www.labnol.org/email-sheet'>Email Spreadsheet add-on</a> for 
  one-click conversion.";
  
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");
  
  blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".pdf");
  
  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments:[blob]     
    }); 
};

function sendSheetToPdfwithA2MailAdress() { // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; // it will send sheet 0 which is the first sheet in the spreadsheet.
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = sh.getName()
  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(0, shName, sh.getRange('A2').getValue()," Test Run ", "Let's Hope This Works");
}

function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;  
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
  
  + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
  // following parameters are optional...
  + '&size=A4'      // paper size
  + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&fith=true'        // fit to height, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
  }
};
```

Comment: I would like for it to work under the onEdit function if possible.

Comment: Does the code you have work? I don't understand why you would want to delete `sendSpreadsheetToPdf()` since you're calling it in `sendSheetToPdfwithA2MailAdress()` (thus it's required). So it makes sense that the code breaks if you delete the function.

Comment: The macro works when i run it separately but when i place it in the onEdit function it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> The macro works when i run it separately but when i place it in the onEdit function it won't work.

Take a look on [Simple Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

**Quote:**

- They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a **simple trigger cannot send an email** because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

If you had used installable triggers instead, you would've had less restrictions (like being able to send emails)

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comment in the question, it's clear that an important part of the code comes from a macro created using the Google Sheets Macro Recorder. Using this tool and the mouse to jump from one cell or range to another, creates a lot of `.activate()` methods which are very slow and it's very likely that this is the causing problems due to the maximum execution limit for simple triggers.

The execution time could be reduced a lot either by recording again the macro but instead of using the mouse use the *Go to range* or the *named range box* to select the ranges to be modified or by [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) the script. See my answer to [Service Spreadsheet Time Out - Optimizing Macro script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73327526/1595451) for details.