# How can I make this code shorter?, Data Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

Please help me to short this code.
This code is for different ranges for dropdowns in each cell of column L. I want this to work upto L200

- For dropdown in cell L3 , range is (''Helper 2'!B1:P1').
- For dropdown in cell L4, range is (''Helper 2'!B2:P2')
- For dropdown in cell L5, range is (''Helper 2'!B3:P3')

And so on.

```
function wa() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L3').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L3:L134').clearDataValidations();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L3').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B1:P1'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B2:P2'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L5').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B3:P3'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L6').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B4:P4'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L7').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B5:P5'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L8').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B6:P6'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L9').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B7:P7'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L10').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B8:P8'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L11').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L11').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B9:P9'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L12').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B10:P10'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L13').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L13').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B11:P11'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L14').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L14').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B12:P12'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L15').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L15').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B13:P13'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L16').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L16').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B14:P14'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L17').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L17').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B15:P15'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L18').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B16:P16'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L19').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B17:P17'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L20').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B18:P18'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L21').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L21').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B19:P19'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('L22').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L22').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Helper 2\'!B20:P20'), true)
  .build());
 spreadsheet.getRange('L1').activate();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you used the macro recorder to generate the code as it includes a lot of `spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate()` like statements that, in this case, are completely unnecessary. To slight shorten your code, remove all of them. This not only will shorten the code but also reduce the execution time.

Also the following lines aren't needed

```
var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
```

To further shorter your code, I suggest you to spend some time learning about the pretty basics of JavaScript, i.e. about variables, functions, data structures, arrays and loops.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Related

- [Service Spreadsheet Time Out - Optimizing Macro script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73327526/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function wa() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Helper 2");
  const rl0 = sh.getRangeList(['B1:P1', 'B2:P2', 'B3:P3', 'B4:P4', 'B5:P5', 'B6:P6', 'B7:P7', 'B8:P8', 'B9:P9', 'B10:P10', 'B11:P11', 'B12:P12', 'B13:P13', 'B14:P14', 'B15:P15', 'B16:P16', 'B17:P17', 'B18:P18', 'B19:P19', 'B20:P20']).getRanges();
  const rl1 = sh.getRangeList(['L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6', 'L7', 'L8', 'L9', 'L10', 'L11', 'L12', 'L13', 'L14', 'L15', 'L16', 'L17', 'L18', 'L19', 'L20', 'L21', 'L22']).getRanges();
  sh.getRange('L3').activate();
  var currentCell = sh.getCurrentCell();
  sh.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  sh.getRange('L3:L134').clearDataValidations();
  rl1.forEach((rg, i) => {
    rg.activate();
    rg.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .setAllowInvalid(true)
    .requireValueInRange(rl0[i],true)
    .build());
  });
  sh.getRange('L1').activate();
};
```